# Resizing Image With Specified Height and Width

Tags: c#

I am trying to resize an image in a folder. The code I am using is this:

```
string logoUrl = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("DeviceLogo");
System.Drawing.Image SourceLogo = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(logoUrl + @"\" + objDevice.FileName);

//Create a logo for this device and reseller/client business              
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(objDevice.LogoWidth, objDevice.LogoHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
{
    graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    graphics.DrawImage(SourceLogo, 0, 0, objDevice.LogoWidth, objDevice.LogoHeight);
}
string filepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("DeviceLogo");                

//Save the resized image                
newImage.Save(filepath + objDevice.FileName);
```

The problem is that the image is not getting resized

Comment: So `objDevice.LogoWidth` and `objDevice.LogoHeight` are the width and height that the image `SourceLogo` is to be resized to?  And they are _not_ the same dimensions as the original size of `SourceLogo`?

Comment: yes the objDevice.LogoWidth and objDevice.LogoHeight is the new resolution of the image

Answer (score 0):

```
using(Image img = Image.FromFile(dlgFichier.FileName))
{
    Image temp = (Image)new Bitmap((Image)img.Clone(), new Size((int)Math.Round(img.Width / ratio), (int)Math.Round(img.Height / ratio)));
    temp.Save("your path");
}
```

try this

/e in my case i wanted to apply a ratio to keep proportionnaly the same height and width
but you can replace *(int)Math.Round(img.Height / ratio)* with your value

/ee replaced my value with yours

```
using(Image img = Image.FromFile(dlgFichier.FileName))
{
    Image temp = (Image)new Bitmap((Image)img.Clone(), new Size(objDevice.LogoWidth, objDevice.LogoHeight));
    temp.Save("your path");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void ResizeImage(Device objDevice)
    {
        string OriginalFile, NewFile;

        OriginalFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("DeviceLogo") + @"\" + objDevice.FileName;
        NewFile = OriginalFile;

        System.Drawing.Image FullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(OriginalFile);

        System.Drawing.Image NewImage = FullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(objDevice.LogoWidth, objDevice.LogoHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);

        // Clear handle to original file so that we can overwrite it if necessary
        FullsizeImage.Dispose();

        // Save resized picture
        NewImage.Save(NewFile);
    }
```

Thanks None for helping